# Visibility of the CSS injected with chrome.tabs.insertCSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension, inject

I did not find anything in the documentation.

I was wondering: is the css injected with *chrome.tabs.insertCSS* visibile to all the elements of the DOM in the tab included the **iframe** coming from other origin?

Comment: Have you already tried it..?

Comment: I didn't. Some adblocks work on it. I would like to read an official documentation or a well documenting explanation on how the css is handled by the Chrome extension engine. :-)